# Guardar valores na váriavel

Tags: php, array

Guardar valores em uma variável vindo por `GET`

Exemplo:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$dados = array($id);
```

Dúvida:

Como guardar todos os ID? Pois eu irei usar esses ID para identificar qual produto foi selecionado.

Criei um carrinho de compras usando SESSION, ao clicar no produto, ele grava na session os dados dele, mas ao clicar no produto, eu estou verificando se o valor do produto é maior que o crédito que o usuário tem, se caso for maior ai ele vai para página para finalizar a compra, caso contrário, ele volta para a página de produtos, mas aparecerá ao usuário os produtos que ele selecionou, ou seja, coloquei um ícone de um VISTO em cima do produto. Mas para colocar esse ícone, eu estou verificando se a $_SESSION['idProduto'] é igual o id do produto

Comment: Guarda em sessão e depois resgata.

Comment: João, pode dar um exemplo?

Comment: $id = $_GET['id']; $id2 = $_GET['id2']; $id3 = $_GET['id3']; $id4 = $_GET['id4']; $dados = new Array($id, $id2, $id3, $id4) Seu código está semelhante a esse?

Comment: @SamirBraga Criei um carrinho de compras usando SESSION, ao clicar no produto, ele grava na session os dados dele, mas ao clicar no produto, eu estou verificando se o valor do produto é maior que o crédito que o usuário tem, se caso for maior ai ele vai para página para finalizar a compra, caso contrário, ele volta para a página de produtos, mas aparecerá ao usuário os produtos que ele selecionou, ou seja, coloquei um ícone de um VISTO em cima do produto. Mas para colocar esse ícone, eu estou verificando se a $_SESSION['idProduto'] é igual o id do produto.

Answer (score 2):

```php
$_SESSION['var'] = array();

array_push($_SESSION['var'], '1'); // adiciona no array
array_push($_SESSION['var'], '2'); // adiciona no array
array_push($_SESSION['var'], '3'); // adiciona no array
array_push($_SESSION['var'], '4'); // adiciona no array

foreach($_SESSION['var'] as $key)
  echo $key.'<br>';
```

http://br.php.net/array_push

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo que use sempre (int)  antes do $_GET['id']. 
Como o id vem via url trata-se de uma string e desta forma com int vamos nos certificar que venhas sempre um número inteiro. 
Use assim:

$id = (int) $_GET['id'];